# Program.exe has stopped working error: fgets function

Tags: c, exe

My program written in C below is running to a certain point. However, it stops in the middle of, what I would deem, error-less code. Coming from Java, I'm a newbie with C so any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getInput(char *input, const char *rs[]){// Args are the user input and our reserved words array.

    printf(">>"); fgets(input, 1000, stdin);// Getting our normal command

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < (int)sizeof(rs); i++){

        if(strcmp(input, rs[i]) != 0){
            printf("You said: %s", input); //PROGRAM BREAKS AFTER THIS LINE
        }

    }

    printf("Size of \"input\" is: %d\n", sizeof(input));// Just checking the size of input

    free(input);// Deallocating input since we won't need it anymore.

}

int main(){

    char *input = malloc(500 * sizeof(char));// Command line input
    const char *rs[1];// Reserved words array.

    rs[0] = "print";

    getInput(input, rs);

    getch();

}
```

Comment: I apologize that the code is improperly formatted. I simply copied and pasted, and that is what resulted.

Comment: 0) `500` <=> `1000` size not match. 1) `sizeof(rs)` and `sizeof(input)` : they  are size of pointer.

Comment: `i < (int)sizeof(rs);` there is no way in C that you can know the number of elements in an array just from a pointer. Note that `main()` takes also an `argc` parameter as well as the `*argv[]`.

Comment: The loop tries to execute more than once, because a) the size is wrong (as @BLUEPIXY said), and b) the input string won't match "print" because `fgets()` will append a `newline` to the input string.

Comment: the posted code does not compile cleanly.  Always enable all compiler warnings when compiling.  Then fix those problems (don't hide them).  Amongst other things, the code is missing the #include <string.h> header file.  line 17 has a format specifier of '%d' when the argument is a 'long unsigned int'.  I don't know where you found 'getch()' but the better call is: 'getchar()'

Comment: when calling malloc() 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the expression: sizeof(char) is defined as 1 and has not effect on the parameter to malloc(),  suggest removing that expression as all it does is clutter the code

Comment: the buffer 'input' is only 500 bytes long so the call to fgets() with a length of 1000 can result in a buffer overrun resulting in undefined behaviour and leading to a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding this line: 'if(strcmp(input, rs[i]) != 0){' rs is a single entry char* that was set to point to the literal 'print' (which as a literal, cannot be modified) so 'rs[i]' is stepping through the char array "print" so the call to strcmp() is looking to see if the input from the user is exactly equal 'prin' which is probably not what you want

Comment: regarding the expression: '(int)sizeof(rs)' the sizeof(rs) will return the sizeof a char*. which will return 4 (the size of a pointer) Remember, sizeof() is a preprocessor operator, not a runtime operator. similar considerations for the expression: 'sizeof(input)' which is also a char* and will return 4   For the 'sizeof(input)' perhaps you meant 'strlen(input)'

Comment: for readability by us humans, only place one statement per line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems, mostly stemming from treating C as if it had strings  and arrays like Java. It doesn't, it just has blocks of bytes and some functions to do string-like and array-like things with them.

So firstly, `malloc(500 * sizeof(char))` allocates 500 bytes (sizeof char is 1 by definition). Later you `fgets(input, 1000...)` on those 500 bytes. Not good.

`char *rs[1]` allocates an array of 1 character pointer. It does not allocate any memory for any strings. `rs[0] = "print"` is OK because "print" allocates 6 bytes and the assignment makes rs[0] point to them. But then you pass `rs` to the function getInput and call `sizeof` on it, which gives you the size of a single pointer (probably 4 or 8 bytes) because C doesn't keep array dimensions either--It just passes a pointer to the start of the array. You need to pass the length yourself.

You aren't checking the return value of `fgets()`. And even if you weren't reading 1000 bytes into a 500-byte buffer and fgets were working perfectly, your `strcmp()` will always fail because `fgets()` includes the newline in the string.

Finally, `sizeof(input)` is another size-of-pointer, not an array dimension. you probably mean `strlen(input)`?

Comment: You're right the size of the pointer always returned 4. Thank you.